# Why isn't getClass() available as a static method?

Tags: java, static

In static contexts, how come you can't call a static version of `getClass()` (rather than having to use `my.package.name.MyClassName.class`) ?

Isn't the compiler smart enough to determine when to use object methods + when to use static methods?

---

NOTE for clarity:

I'm not saying that a `static getClass()` should be used *instead* of the non-static method `getClass()` (that's kind of obvious -- if `SpecialFoo` is a subclass of `Foo`, then the `getClass()` of a `Foo` could return `Foo.class` or `SpecialFoo.class` or something else and it has to be determined at runtime).

I'm saying that I'm wondering why aren't there *two* versions of `getClass()`, one that is a static method which only applies in a static context, and the regular non-static method `getClass()`.  If it's not possible, then it's not possible, and that's the answer. If it's possible but just hasn't been done, then it's a historical choice, and maybe there's a good reason for it. That's what I'd like to know.

It would be great to declare

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

instead of

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(my.package.name.MyClass.class);
```

where the former could be copied verbatim from one class to the next, whereas the latter requires you to copy the class name in each file.

Comment: Good question. Groovy allows `this` to reference the *current class* in a static context ;-)

Comment: Probably because at runtime static methods do not have any class context.

Comment: Right, but from the compiler's point of view, when you call a static method `foo()`, it knows `foo()` refers to the static method. I guess what I'm asking is why there isn't a `getClass()` static method that returns the builtin static `.class` field.

Comment: It seems likely that there is no getClass() because back in the day, the developers of the java language put in the .class property and thought "that is good enough". Much like the Array.length property.

Comment: Possibly a method is not the correct solution, but **some** way to reference the `Class` object of the current class would be nice. Maybe `this.class` as a special case of the `Class` literal always referring to the class containing the expression.

Comment: @DwB: I guess I should re-title; my point isn't so much why *isn't* it present, but is it possible for this to be done.

Comment: If it is *possible* but just isn't implemented, then I'd nominate for the next Project-Coin-like effort. My code is full of `final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(my.package.name.MyClassName.class)` lines which are not easily maintainable.

Comment: Why the fully qualified name of the class when you're in that class already? `MyClassName.class` should suffice.

Comment: Not sure why you think that's not easily maintainable. Since you're adding that logger init within the same class the class name should never change unless you actually rename that class and it's compilation unit which is very uncommon. Also as colinD said, the package is redundant, you're already in the class you don't need it.

Comment: @Jberg: DRY -- it's when you're copying code from one class to another. As far as renaming, Eclipse's refactoring handles that case correctly.

Comment: Looks like it's time for me to use another Lombok feature -- http://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else, because it isn't legal to have both a `static` and non-`static` version of a method (probably because it's legal, if discouraged, to call a `static` method in a non-`static` context).

I also feel like such a method, while useful in the context of defining a logger or whatever, could be confusing in other contexts, such as when called from an instance method.

Answer (score 26):

You can use this idiom

```
    Class<?> cl=new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
```

For example:

```
static class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> cl=new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
        System.out.println(cl==Bar.class);  //will print true
    }
}
```

Comment: I always get null using this method. Does it depend on Bar being a static class?

Comment: You might have written `new Object().getClass().getEnclosingClass()`. The correct way is to use `new Object(){}`, which defines and instantiates an anonymous class based on `Object`.

Answer (score 7):

Each object is an instance of a class in Java and no class can be an instance of another class! Which is why getClass() is not static as it only makes sense in the context of an object : you are trying to find for an object what class is it an instance of.
If it was a static function, it can be called outside an object -- but it doesn't make sense to write

```
String.getClass()
```

because you already know you're "asking" the String class!

Comment: right -- I understood that when writing my question. See the edits.

Comment: it adds no value for use *outside* the class, but it does add value for use *inside* the class.

Answer (score 5):

getClass() provides a different functionality than the static .class.  It's used to get the run time class of the instance it's called on.

```
Object o = new String();
o.getClass() // returns Class<String>    
Object.class // returns Class<Object>
```

Comment: yes, of course -- sorry, I didn't make myself clear in my original question. see my edits.

Comment: Gotcha, seems someone else has already given this answer, but most likely it's because you can't overload method names with the static keyword alone. You'd need a second method with a different name or parameters. My guess would be that they thought that would be unnecessary and/or confusing to add a second getClass method. I guess they figured nobody would have a problem just using the static .class property.

Answer (score 2):

Because if `getClass()` would be static, its code would have to be defined in one class - probably `Object`. There, you can't determine the *callers* class and there isn't an object instance who calls it.

Edit:

It's not about the name; it could be very well  `getClass2()`. I'm saying that if you define a static method, you can't know the class that calls it:

```
public class Object {

    public static Class<?> getClass2() {
        return ...?
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a similar trick at work with `Enum.getValues()`: it's a static method that's available on each `enum` (a.k.a. "each subclass of `java.lang.Enum`). Something similar would be thinkable here.

Comment: I'm not saying that it should be *instead* of the non-static method `getClass()` (that's kind of obvious -- if `SpecialFoo` is a subclass of `Foo`, then the `getClass()` of a `Foo` could return `Foo.class` or `SpecialFoo.class` or something else). I'm saying that in a static context why isn't there a second *static* version of getClass().

Comment: @Jason S - You can't declare two methods which differentiate only on the static keyword:)

Comment: OK, then that's the answer, so they'd have to have two different names in order to implement.

Comment: @Joachim, I think you mean `values()` from `enum`, not `getValues()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement one yourself. Get the stacktrace, and find the caller class.

Actually the logger lib could implemented that itself

```
static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(); // auto detect caller class
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a static `getClass()` method return the class object the class the variable which holds the object is from? That would change the semantics of `getClass()`. Example:

```
Interface foo = new FooImpl(); 
foo.getClass(); // returns Class<FooImpl> because the runtime type is FooImpl. 
                // If getClass() was static, it would return Class<Foo>.
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of other answers (which explain why we can't make a static method with the same signature as the non-static 'getClass()' method), one would wonder if it would possible to have, say a `static Class getStaticClass()` so that, for example `String.getStaticClass()` would be equivalent to `String.class`. But, again, this method could not be a "normal" method Where would it be defined? in Object? Then how would this single method know what to return (String.class or Object.class) when it was called as String.getStaticClass() or Object.getStaticClass() ? Would it decide it in runtime ? No way.

A static method does not make sense because `String.class` is known (resolved) at compile time. The method has no reasonable thing to do at runtime; you'd have to do some compilation magic so that the result of that method call is actually resolved at compile time.